# Android pull to refresh with ScrollView control

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, pull-to-refresh

I am using a ScrollView to display a list of items that are inflated on runtime. Like a feed of updates for the user. 
While thinking about the options i got to let the user update the view with new notifications I thought about the pull to refresh feature in the twitter app.

Anyone got any idea how and if can it be implemented with a ScrollView ?

Saw there are some implementations for that using ListView but I don't like the idea of changing all of my platform to gain this refresh effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution introduced for implementing pull to refresh for various component which are scrollable like listview and scroollview.
Look at ChangeLog link [https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/)

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` with just one element can be treated as a `ScrollView`. You can use the implementation for pull-to-refresh `ListView` and add just one item in it. I had used this trick in the past.

Comment: Was looking for a more elegant way... I'll give it a try.

Comment: 500865 - can you explain further, how you did it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. You can increase the top margin of the scrollview when the user moves the finger down and the scrollview it's on it's top. Then on release fire the update and decrease the margin with animation.(You have to create your own animation to pull that off). That's the idea. If you want more particular help ask what you cannot implement.

Comment: Meaning i will have to place a view behind the scroll view. then when the user pulls down and the margin increases i will have to ensure the background view will stay sticky to the top of the scroll view... Is that what you meant ?

Comment: well that a way to pull that off too. I don't think there is a best way to do that. Only keep in mind to use as fewer views as possible and populate or show them only when you need to.